# Qtcreator get stdin from a file instead of terminal

Tags: c++, c, qt-creator

I am making a program that reads from `stdin`.

I want to debug the program in qtcreator but I can't find a way of providing input except using the terminal. Which is not very practical because my input is a big file with a lot of lines.

I tried going to the run options of qtcreator and insert the following in the Command Line Arguments: `< filename`

But Qtcreator gave me an error in the application output:
`14:26:54: Debugging complex shell commands in a terminal is currently not supported.`

Is there no way of providing a file as stdin in qtcreator?

Comment: Do you use c++ std::cin for your data input ? if yes, you can redirect the input file `filename`to std::cin.

Comment: No answer because I'm not using QtCreator for the moment, but as a workaround, you could add a -i commandline argument that reads from a file instead of stdin and initialize your inputstream with the file or stdin, so you can at least continue debugging (and maybe some users would prefer this over redirecting input when using your program). Still, it is weird that QtCreator still doesn't support this.

Comment: I tried a test in Qt creator 3.1.2 and it works, it accepts the `< filename` as expected. So @AdamZahran can detail the development environment?

Comment: Qtcreator 4.8.0 on ubuntu 18.04